# Maximum value of generic polynomial with evenly spaced roots on interval [0, 1]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Is there a compact form for value:

$$V_n = \max_{0 \le x \le 1} \left| \prod_{i=0}^n \left(x-\frac{i}{n}\right)\right|$$

I calculated $V_1=\frac{1}{4}, V_2=\frac{1}{12\sqrt3}, V_3=\frac{1}{81}$, but I don't see a pattern. Some resonable upper-bounds (dependent of $n$) also will be helpful.

Comment: For an upper bound see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087077/proving-the-inequality-left-prod-i-0n-leftx-fracin-right-right

Comment: Thank you, this upper bound is good enough for my problem.